# Private End point connection Azure SQL database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I already have a private end point for Azure SQL Server. How can I configure that private end point for Azure SQL database while creating Linked Service in Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a linked service of Azure SQL database with private endpoint configuration, follow the procedure below:

1. Create an integration runtime with virtual network configuration as shown below:

[image]

2. Go to the Azure Data Factory manage tab and create a new private endpoint by clicking the "New" option. Select the Azure SQL database option and choose your server name from the list. Click on "Create." This action will require approval from the SQL server.
3. In the SQL server, go to the networking tab and select "Private Access." You will see a hyperlink that leads you to approve the private endpoint at the SQL server level. Click on the hyperlink and approve it, as shown below:

[image]

4. After approving successfully, create a new SQL database linked service using the previously created integration runtime with the required details. The linked service will be created successfully, as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by Creating a Private Endpoint for Azure SQL Database and then Create a Linked Service in Azure Data Factory and finally Configure the Private Endpoint URL in Linked Service.

This is how the configuration looks like

```html
{
    "name": "<YourLinkedServiceName>",
    "properties": {
        "type": "<LinkedServiceType>",
        "typeProperties": {
            "connectionString": "Data Source=<your-server-name>.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=<your-database-name>;User ID=<your-username>;Password=<your-password>"
        }
    }
}
```